# Custom String to Date object in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following array representing week numbers:

```
arr= ["W22", "W4"]
```

I want to be able to do for use in my scale object:

```
d3.min(arr) === "W4" (TRUE)
d3.max(arr) === "W22" (TRUE)
```

This will be used for string interpolation for my time axis.

What I have been trying is using:

```
week = d3.time.format("%W").parse;
```

The problem is that im lost on how to use this when I have the week format in a string with "W" in front of the week number.

UPDATE---
As pere sugestion I have changed to:

week = d3.time.format("W%W").parse;

However no matter what i send I get the same return.

week("W2")
week("W52")

They return

```
Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

Comment: `d3.time.format("W%W")`

Comment: No matter what I put in to that method I get the same answere. Se updated description in OP.

Comment: I think this might be a bug in `d3`. Even supplying a year which should be sufficient to calculate the week doesn't produce the correct result. I filed a new github issue.

Comment: See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1914.  To parse using %W you need to also supply %w.